# Java Swing Calculator

Tags: java, swing, calculator

I've been learning java for over a year and I'm looking for better ways to learn and I'm trying to get a better idea of where I am as a programmer. I honestly have no clue if my code is good or bad. I'd really appreciate it if you could have a look at my code and point out anything that's wrong with it. The calculator has the same functionality as the Windows 7 calculator and it's split into 3 classes.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.script.ScriptException;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Calculator extends JFrame implements Runnable {

private MemoryStore memoryStore = new MemoryStore();
private JTextPane screen;
private JPanel buttonPanel;
private JButton[] numberButtons;
private JButton[] operationButtons;
private String display = "";
private boolean shouldOverwrite = false;
private String[] operationButtonStrings = { "ME", "MR", "MS", "M+", "M-", "←", "C", "+", "-", "*", "/", "√", "x²",
        "±", "%", ".", "1/x", "=" };

public Calculator() {
    super("Java Calculator");
}

@Override
public void run() {
    makeGUI();
}

private void makeGUI() {
    frameSetup();
    screenSetup();
    createNumberButtons();
    createOperationButtons();
    addButtons();
    setVisible(true);
}

private void frameSetup() {
    setSize(300, 300);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Open frame in middle of screen
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

private void screenSetup() {
    screen = new JTextPane();
    screen.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(1));
    screen.setEditable(false);
    screen.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.BOLD, 18));
    add(screen, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}

private void createNumberButtons() {
    MyNumberButtonListener numberButtonListener = new MyNumberButtonListener();
    numberButtons = new JButton[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        numberButtons[i] = new JButton(Integer.toString(i));
        numberButtons[i].addActionListener(numberButtonListener);
        numberButtons[i].setFocusable(false);
    }
}

private void createOperationButtons() {
    MyOperationButtonListener operationButtonListener = new MyOperationButtonListener();
    operationButtons = new JButton[18];
    for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
        operationButtons[i] = new JButton(operationButtonStrings[i]);
        operationButtons[i].addActionListener(operationButtonListener);
        operationButtons[i].setFocusable(false);
    }

}

private void addButtons() {
    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 5, 1, 1));
    buttonPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        buttonPanel.add(numberButtons[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
        buttonPanel.add(operationButtons[i]);
    }

    buttonPanel.add(new JButton());
    buttonPanel.add(new JButton());
    add(buttonPanel);

}

private class MyNumberButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (e.getSource() == numberButtons[i]) {
                displayNumber(i);
                break;
            }
        }

    }

}

private void displayNumber(int number) {
    if (shouldOverwrite) {
        screen.setText("" + number);
        shouldOverwrite = false;
    } else {
        display = screen.getText();
        screen.setText(display + number);
    }
}

private class MyOperationButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == operationButtons[0]) {
            memoryStore.resetStoredValue();
        } else if (e.getSource() == operationButtons[1]) {
            display = screen.getText();
            screen.setText(display + "" + memoryStore.getStoredValue());
        } else if (e.getSource() == operationButtons[2]) {
            if (!screenIsEmpty())
                memoryStore.store(readScreenAsDouble());
        } else if (e.getSource() == operationButtons[3]) {
            if (!screenIsEmpty())
                memoryStore.plusStoredValue(readScreenAsDouble());
        } else if (e.getSource() == operationButtons[4]) {
            if (!screenIsEmpty())
                memoryStore.minusStoredValue(readScreenAsDouble());
        } else if (e.getSource() == operationButtons[5]) {
            backSpace();
        } else if (e.getSource() == operationButtons[6]) {
            clearScreen();
        } else if (e.getSource() == operationButtons[7]) {
            displaySymbol(operationButtons[7].getText());
        } else if (e.getSource() == operationButtons[8]) {
            displaySymbol(operationButtons[8].getText());
        } else if (e.getSource() == operationButtons[9]) {
            displaySymbol(operationButtons[9].getText());
        } else if (e.getSource() == operationButtons[10]) {
            displaySymbol(operationButtons[10].getText());
        } else if (e.getSource() == operationButtons[11]) {
            writeToScreen(CalcUtilities.sqrRoot(readScreenAsDouble()));
            shouldOverwrite = true;
        } else if (e.getSource() == operationButtons[12]) {
            writeToScreen(CalcUtilities.squared(readScreenAsDouble()));
            shouldOverwrite = true;
        } else if (e.getSource() == operationButtons[13]) {
            changeToPlusOrMinus();
        } else if (e.getSource() == operationButtons[14]) {
            displaySymbol(operationButtons[14].getText());
        } else if (e.getSource() == operationButtons[15]) {
            if (!displayHasDecimal())
                displaySymbol(operationButtons[15].getText());
        } else if (e.getSource() == operationButtons[16]) {
            writeToScreen(CalcUtilities.reciprocal(readScreenAsDouble()));
            shouldOverwrite = true;
        } else if (e.getSource() == operationButtons[17]) {
            equalsAction();
        }

    }

}

private double readScreenAsDouble() {
    double result;
    display = screen.getText();
    result = parseDisplayToDouble(display);
    return result;
}

private void writeToScreen(double numToWrite) {
    screen.setText(Double.toString(numToWrite));
}

public double parseDisplayToDouble(String display) {
    double result;
    try {
        result = Double.parseDouble(display);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return 0.0;
    }
    return result;
}

private void displaySymbol(String symbol) {
    display = screen.getText();
    screen.setText(display + symbol);
    shouldOverwrite = false;
}

private void clearScreen() {
    screen.setText("");
}

private boolean displayHasDecimal() {
    display = screen.getText();
    if (display.indexOf('.') != -1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

private void equalsAction() {
    display = screen.getText();
    try {
        screen.setText(CalcUtilities.evaluate(display) + "");
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
        screen.setText("Invalid");
    }
    shouldOverwrite = true;
}

private void backSpace() {
    if (!screenIsEmpty()) {
        display = screen.getText();
        screen.setText(display.substring(0, display.length() - 1));
    }

}

private void changeToPlusOrMinus() {
    display = screen.getText().toString();
    if (display.charAt(0) != '-')
        screen.setText("-" + display);
    else
        screen.setText(display.substring(1, display.length()));
    shouldOverwrite = false;
}

private boolean screenIsEmpty() {
    display = screen.getText().toString();
    if (display.equals(""))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

}
```

```
/*
 * Author: Alex Matthews
 * Ireland
 */ 
import javax.script.*;

public class CalcUtilities {

private static ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
private static ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

public static double reciprocal(double num) {
    return 1 / num; 
}


public static double squared(double num) {
    return num * num;
}

public static double sqrRoot(double num) {
    return Math.sqrt(num);
}

public static Object evaluate(String equation) throws ScriptException {
    return engine.eval(equation);
}
}
```

```
/*
 * Author: Alex Matthews
 * Ireland
 */ 
public class MemoryStore {

    private double storedVal = 0.0;

    public void store(double num) {
        storedVal = num;
    }

    public double getStoredValue() {
        return storedVal;
    }

    public void resetStoredValue() {
        storedVal = 0.0;
    }

    public void plusStoredValue(double num) {
        storedVal += num;
    }

    public void minusStoredValue(double num) {
        storedVal -= num;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Pros:

- basic *separation of concerns*:

  - you have separate Listeners for Number buttons and operator buttons
  - you created small methods with limited concerns.
  - you created two arrays to hold buttons of same type but different business roles.
- Naming: you follow the Java naming conventions and your identifier have useful names.
- comments: you have a comment which tells *why* the code is at that line. You have no other comments.

### cons:

#### inheritance misconception:

Your class  `Calculator` extends `JFrame`, but it does not add new functionality to it, it just configures the frame.

#### `if`/`else` cascade instead of polymorphism

The method `actionPerformed()` Your class `MyOperationButtonListener` contains a long `if`/`else` cascade. This is because you have to know which button caused the event.

This could be avoided if you had a separate Listener instance for each button. This does not mean that a separate Listener *class* is needed for each button. The listeners should have been created as *anonymous inner classes* of the `ActionListener` interface directly.

The downside of it that you cannot create the operator buttons in a loop anymore, but this is ok because each button ha a different behavior:

```
private void createOperationButtons() {
    operationButtons = new JButton[18];
        operationButtons[0] = new JButton("ME"); // the array operationButtonStrings is not needed.
        operationButtons[0].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              memoryStore.resetStoredValue();
           }
        });    
        operationButtons[0].setFocusable(false);

        operationButtons[1] = new JButton("MR"); // the array operationButtonStrings is not needed.
        operationButtons[1].addActionListener((e) -> { // java8 lambda version
             display = screen.getText();
             screen.setText(display + "" + memoryStore.getStoredValue());
        });    
        operationButtons[1].setFocusable(false);
       // ...
    }
}
```

To reduce the code duplication youcould extract the actual buton cration and configuration in an extra method:

```
private JButton createButton(String text, ActionListener action){
    JButton button = new JButton(text);
    button.addActionListener(action);
    button.setFocusable(false);
    return button;
}

private void createOperationButtons() {
    operationButtons = new JButton[18];
        operationButtons[0] = createButton("ME",(e)->memoryStore.resetStoredValue());
        operationButtons[1] = createButton("MR",(e)->{
             display = screen.getText();
             screen.setText(display + "" + memoryStore.getStoredValue());
        });
    // ....
}
```

As you can see this brings the "name" and the "function" closer together and does not need any `if`/`else` cascade or `switch`...

---

> I have to do it 18 times in one method it makes the method very big and ugly. There has to be a way of making it nice and clean. – Alex. M

You cannot avoid having to specify the different behavior for the operator buttons.

In your first solution the ugliness was the `if`/`else` cascade in your `actionPerformed()` method.

With my suggestion you could at least ease the readers pain by having an additional method for each operator button:

```
private JButton createButton(String text, ActionListener action){
    JButton button = new JButton(text);
    button.addActionListener(action);
    button.setFocusable(false);
    return button;
}

private JButton createMemoryEraseButton(){
    return createButton("ME",(e)->memoryStore.resetStoredValue());
}

private JButton createMemoryRecallButton(){
    return createButton("MR",(e)->{
             display = screen.getText();
             screen.setText(display + "" + memoryStore.getStoredValue());
        });
}
// ....

private JButton[] createOperationButtons() {
    operationButtons = new JButton[] {
       createMemoryEraseButton(),
       createMemoryRecallButton(),
       // ....
    };
    return operationButtons;
}
```

You could even go one step further and move the method `createOperationButtons()` and all the `create??Button()` methods in to a separate class.

Off cause, all the objects these methods work on  you would have to pass in as prarameters either to the constructor of the new class or the `createOperationButtons()` method and subsequently to the `create??Button()` methods as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have tried changing it to use the lambda expressions and the create button method in order to create the operation buttons but since I have to do it 18 times in one method it makes the method very big and ugly. There has to be a way of making it nice and clean.